# Huge performance drop for LIKE statement if column order changes in composite index

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

Edit:
EXPLAIN result for the first two queries when using src_cus_lang:
[image]
EXPLAIN result for the last two queries when using cust_lang_src:
[image]

Original post:
I'm using MySQL and have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tm(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    source TEXT(7000) NOT NULL,
    target TEXT(6000) NOT NULL,
    language CHAR(3),
    customer VARCHAR(10))
```

When using composite index `(source(755), customer, language)`, the fetch times are as follows:

```
SELECT source FROM tm WHERE customer = 'Customer A' AND language = 'ENU' AND source LIKE '%.net%';  -- 0.015s
SELECT source FROM tm WHERE source LIKE '%.net%' AND customer = 'Customer A' AND language = 'ENU';  -- 0.015s
```

However, when using composite index `(customer, language, source(755))`, the fetch times increased drastically:

```
SELECT source FROM tm WHERE customer = 'Customer A' AND language = 'ENU' AND source LIKE '%.net%';  -- 1.7s
SELECT source FROM tm WHERE source LIKE '%.net%' AND customer = 'Customer A' AND language = 'ENU';  -- 1.7s
```

This is contrary to what I found somewhere on the Internet, which claims that the leftmost prefix rule is applied until `<`, `>`, `BETWEEN` or `LIKE` is met. According to this claim, the `(customer, language, source(755))` index would be faster than `(source(755), customer, language)` index regarding fetch time, since `source` is used with `LIKE`. I can't post the source, because it's not in English. Is this claim wrong? If not, why did I see contrary results?

Comment: You have misread or misunderstood it.  Your results are as expected.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta You mean that claim is correct?

Comment: The villain is the `(755)`.  Using that construct is rarely useful, and, as you just found, it may be counterproductive.  Try just `INDEX(customer, language)`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In addition to what Bill says...)

This may be the best:

```
PRIMARY KEY(customer, language, id),  -- to optimize the query (and maybe others)
INDEX(id)   -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

Probably your first two tries were "fast" because they ignored the index.  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to verify.

Comment: I added the EXPLAIN results above. The first two queries did ignore the index. The last two queries used their `(customer, language, source(755))` index, but are still slower than the first two queries. It seems the `(customer, language, source(755))` index only does harm and no good, even though the first two columns in it seem useful.

Comment: BTW, therer are only two customers and two languages, so the index might not be selective enough. So maybe this is why the first two columns in `(customer, language, source(755))` didn't contribute much. And there's only `source(755)` left to blame. Do you think it will do any harm to the query if no good?

Comment: Yes, (755) is the villain; so is the lack of selectivity of the others.  Bouncing between the index BTree and the data BTree is a cost.  What percentage of the rows are returned by the queries?

Comment: 9,000  out of 1,000,000. Nearly 1%.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition `source LIKE '%.net%'` cannot use an index. The wildcard at the start of your pattern makes the index useless, because the index entries are sorted from the start of the string.

By analogy, think of a telephone book. It's sorted by names. Can you find entries with "net" *in the middle of the name* efficiently? No, because the sort order of the book doesn't help at all.

Since that condition cannot use an index, the index on `(source(755), customer, language)` cannot be used. It can't use the first column, so it can't use any subsequent columns.

The index on `(customer, language, source(755))` can be used, but only for the first two columns. The `LIKE` condition still ignores the index, but at least the search can be narrowed down using the first two columns.

The telephone book analogy may help here too. If you search for someone with last name 'Smith' and whose first name contains "net" anywhere within the name, then at least you can limit your search to a subset of the book, people whose last name matches your condition on last name. But the first name still cannot be optimized; you just have to read through all the Smiths and evaluate them one by one.

Comment: I added the EXPLAIN results above. As it turns out, the first two queries didn't use any index. And even though the last two queries used `(customer, language, source(755))` and the first two columns in the index can be useful, it is still slower than the first two queries which did not use any index. This is still strange. It seems `(customer, language, source(755))` only does harm and no good.

Comment: BTW, therer are only two customers and two languages, so the index might not be selective enough. So maybe this is why the first two columns in (customer, language, source(755)) didn't contribute much. And there's only source(755) left to blame. Do you think it will do any harm to the query if no good?

Comment: MySQL will not use the index if it estimates that using the index doesn't help. You can see this when the EXPLAIN says `type: ALL`. This is a table-scan.